XCode ‘New File’ has started only giving me a single platform option vision OS
This option is now always giving me a single choice to 'choose a template' ... 'visionOS'. visionOS is not a project target, nor was it even a thing when the project was started.
How do I get to create files such as a SwiftUI view?
How can I see the iOS macOS platform options etc.
XCode 15.4
File > New > File  (and plus sign, from different locations in the project hierarchy)
enter image description here
I can select visionOS and get told that my Intel Mac is not suitable (I know).
enter image description here
